# Creating a circle with different touchable areas in iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I want to create a circle. This circle will have four parts, and I want to make each of this part to be touchable.

For example, if I press part 1 to have action A, and when I press part 2 to have action B, etc.

I suppose I could draw the circle with openGL or to use a prepared image.

How can this be done?

Comment: I will recommend you to look at the ["How To Create a Rotating Wheel Control with UIKit"](http://www.raywenderlich.com/9864/how-to-create-a-rotating-wheel-control-with-uikit) page!.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you draw a circle with OpenGL?

You can subclass a `UIView` and do your drawing in `-drawRect:` and use the `UIView`s hit detection to determine the touch location with `-touchesBegan:...` etc.

If you want something more lightweight you can implement the same with `CALayer`s and it's `-hitTest:` methods.

Here's a example for drawing

```
@implementation MYView

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
  [[UIColor blackColor] set];
  UIBezierPath *circle = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:self.bounds];
  [circle fill];
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I didn't understand what you mean. You mean to draw the circle inside the Rectangle ? isn't this the same to draw the circle in OpenGL with using of cos and sin of an angle? the easiest way is to use an ready images, but is there a way to implement them ?

Comment: `UIView` has a method named `- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect` where you can draw all sorts of stuff (you need to override it).

Comment: isn't this the same to draw the circle in OpenGL with using of cos and sin of an angle? the easiest way is to use an ready images, but is there a way to implement them ?

Comment: You are very, very wrong. Have a look at the drawing guide: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: Thank you very much for the code. Yes I done this. But now when i divide the circle into 4 parts, how to get the whole points coordinates inside each part. I want each part to to do separate actions